# Output stats on the values in a list (Python)

Tags: python

I am able to produce an output, but there is a space before each period that I do not know how to remove.

```
num = int(input())
numList=[]
add=0
for i in range(0,num):
    n = int(input())
    numList.append(n)
    add=add+numList[i]
avg=add/num
avg = float("{:.2f}".format(avg))
print("The grades you input are",numList,'.')
print("The average of the grades is",avg, '.')
print("The grades below the average are:")
for val in numList:
    if(val<avg):
        print(val)
```

For example, if the input is:
6
80
75
100
96
82
93

The output should be:

```
The grades you input are [80, 75, 100, 96, 82, 93].
The average of the grades is 87.67.
```

The output I am recieving is:

```
The grades you input are [80, 75, 100, 96, 82, 93] .
The average of the grades is 87.67 .
```

Comment: Use `sep=''` to get rid of the space separator that `print()` uses by default.

Comment: Then you'll need to add spaces after `are` and `is`.

Comment: Or you could use an f-string to format everything exactly as you want, instead of using the default formatting of `print()`.

Comment: where should I add sep=' '

Comment: Click on the linked question above.